# Huge padding in powershell created webparts

Tags: web-part, css, powershell

I add a webpart page via powershell like this:

```
$idLayout = 2
$list = $oSP.GetList( $sList )
$xml  = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><Method ID=""0,NewWebPage""><SetList Scope=""Request"">"
$xml += $list.ID
$xml += "</SetList><SetVar Name=""Cmd"">NewWebPage</SetVar><SetVar Name=""ID"">New</SetVar><SetVar Name=""Type"">WebPartPage</SetVar><SetVar Name=""WebPartPageTemplate"">"
$xml += $idLayout
$xml += "</SetVar><SetVar Name=""Overwrite"">true</SetVar><SetVar Name=""Title"">"
$xml += $sName
$xml += "</SetVar></Method>"
$result = $oSP.ProcessBatchData($xml)
```

It works, but the webparts have huge padding (see screenshot). How can I have the normal padding for webpart pages w/o hacking CSS?

[image]

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot I can see only webpart zones? Are you talking about the padding that is there in the zone?

Comment: Excatly, if I add anything in the webparts the padding is still that large, as you can see in the second screenshot I just added.

Comment: It seems like issue with your page layout.

Comment: hmm that's basically SP OOTB.. I didn't modify anything.. I removed all custom CSS (border for webpart) and reposted the screenshot.. same difference. The code to create the webpart is correct, right?

Comment: Yes. To prove this, create a new webpart page and add the webpart manually. If the padding is wrong in that page, that means the issue is with the Site CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in CSS of your masterpage or as part of editor web part custom css to see if it helps.

```
<style type="text/css">
 .ms-webpartPage-root {
 border-spacing: 0px !important;
 }
   .ms-webpartzone-cell {
     margin: 0px !important;
 }
```